# "Trying to get property of non-object" Laravel

Tags: laravel

i have some problem...
here is my code..
i can't get what i swrong with my code.....

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1o7z.jpg)
[here is my user class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBjru.jpg)

this is the full DashboardController

```
/**
 * '/home' calls this route
 *
 * @param none
 * @return view dashboard
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->permission();
    $data = [
        'pagetitle' => 'Dashboard',
        'permission' => Session()->get('permission'),
        'name' => Auth::user()->name,
    ];
    return view('dashboard',$data);
}


/**
 * Checks if session has permission in it if not they adds to it
 *
 * @param null
 * @return null
 */
private function permission()
{
    if (!Session()->has('permission')) {
        $permission = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->details;
        $permission_arr = [
            'department' => $permission->permission_department,
            'asset' => $permission->permission_asset,
            'users' => $permission->permission_users,
        ];

        Session()->put('permission', $permission_arr);
    }
}
```

}

i have no idea how solve it..
any help would be great..

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, could you also provide the code for the User class? :)

Comment: hi could you add the exact error in your question .. “Trying to get property of non-object” means you are trying to access a child of your model when there's really no child at all ..

Comment: @Newbie show ur user model

Comment: thank you for you guys that help me... finally i can't figure it out whats wrong in my codes. especially to @Demonyowh who help me understand something here...

Comment: and thanks also to @JigneshJoisar for the sample codes :)

Answer (score 1):

You get this kind of problem for you are getting only access of **details** column From your User table . Remove the details from $permission = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

```
private function permission(){
  if (!Session()->has('permission')){
     $permission = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
     $permission_arr = [
        'department' => $permission->permission_department,
        'asset' => $permission->permission_asset,
        'users' => $permission->permission_users,
     ];

     Session()->put('permission', $permission_arr);
  }
}
```

**Note** I have only remove the details object from your permission variable